# I can't load tailwind styles to blade components in laravel-jetstream

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-jetstream

i started a project with laravel jetstream and i can't load the tailwind styles. i tried to put it in the components and also in the welcome page. i don't get results. here is the code. in the view it is not shown with styles.

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mx-auto">
        <h1 class="">Welcome to hell!</h1>
        <h2>Welcome to Paradise</h2>
        <div class="bg-red-200 border-red-500 text-red-700 border-l-4 p-4" role="alert">
            <p class="font-bold">Be Warned!</p>
            <p>Something not ideal might be happening.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: did you install jetstream with livewire or vue/inertia?

Comment: livewire! it's solved tho. all i had to do was clear the cache and run npm run dev.

Answer (score 0):

This has been very tricky for some people when using Laravel with Tailwind as a CSS framework.

Mostly the little you can do is include your `blade.php` path in Tailwind's config file which is found in your root path as `tailwind.config.js`

You can set the content object as follows:

```
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And you can see .js and .vue in there that means only if you are using it with a specific JavaScript framework.

Another advanced way can be, loading all available files that can possibly be using Tailwind Utility classes.

```
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.{blade.php,js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue,html}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}", 
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This can be considered when using a JavaScript Framework such as Vue or ReactJS and so you will only use the appropriate `.extension`

This is an example to get a broad understanding of configuring all files that can contain Tailwind Utility classes so that it can be applied when building the final stylesheet.

I hope this answer helps.